# XGBoosterPredict second call overwrites previous

Tags: c++, reference, xgboost

In the code below second call to XGBoosterPredict overwrites train_out_pb,
problem is probably very trivial but I cannot see it.

debugger output after 1.st call:

- &train_out_pb 0x06d0eb2c {0x0074d060 {0.410961390}}   const float * *
- &val_out_pb   0x06d0eb28 {0xffffffff {???}}   const float * *

debugger output after 2nd call:

- &train_out_pb 0x06d0eb2c {0x0074d060 {0.522293866}}   const float * *
- &val_out_pb   0x06d0eb28 {0x0074d060 {0.522293866}}   const float * *

Code:

```
bst_ulong train_pred_len;
const float* train_out_pb = new float[train_num_samples]; //()
//1.st call
ret = XGBoosterPredict(h_booster, XY_train, 0, 0, &train_pred_len, &train_out_pb);

bst_ulong val_pred_len;
const float* val_out_pb = new float[val_num_samples];
//2.nd call
ret = XGBoosterPredict(h_booster, XY_val, 0, 0, &val_pred_len, &val_out_pb);
```

excerpt from XGBoost c_api.cc:

```
XGB_DLL int XGBoosterPredict(BoosterHandle handle,
                     DMatrixHandle dmat,
                     int option_mask,
                     unsigned ntree_limit,
                     xgboost::bst_ulong *len,
                     const bst_float **out_result) 
{
std::vector<bst_float>& preds = XGBAPIThreadLocalStore::Get()->ret_vec_float;
API_BEGIN();
Booster *bst = static_cast<Booster*>(handle);
bst->LazyInit();

bst->learner()->Predict(
  static_cast<std::shared_ptr<DMatrix>*>(dmat)->get(),
  (option_mask & 1) != 0,
  &preds, ntree_limit,
  (option_mask & 2) != 0);
*out_result = dmlc::BeginPtr(preds);
*len = static_cast<xgboost::bst_ulong>(preds.size());
API_END();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but a solution nonetheless is to store overwritten variable in other variable

```
        const float* train_out_pb;

        ret = XGBoosterPredict(h_booster, XY_train, 0, 0, &train_pred_len, &train_out_pb);

        std::vector<float> train_out_pb_v(train_out_pb, train_out_pb + train_pred_len);
```